# turn regex rule in a mysql regex rule

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

after time of work and reserch i found the perfect rule to check if `[batt, lk, elem]` *all words are between 2 symbols " **;** " in any order*.

In the next example the "sentences"  are splitted by " ; " so for example:

```
 ;first sentence; second sentece; third sentence;
```

regex ->    `(?=;.*batt)(?=;.*lk)(?=;.*elem)`

Real examples:

```
; lk Buttle, batt; Probatton with LK elements; -> FOUND

;look Buttle; Proton with LK elements; -> NOT FOUND (not all 3 words are in the first OR in the second sentence)

;Brad Pitt the actor; LK elements in Battle; -> FOUND (the 3 words are in the second sentece)

;Brad Pitt the actor; LK elements in; Battle; -> not FOUND ("Battle" [root:'batt'] is in a different sentence)
```

When applyed this one to a mySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` pl WHERE pl.`description` REGEXP '(?=;.*batt)(?=;.*lk)(?=;.*elem)'
```

I figure out that the *regex-lazy-operation* cannot works.

How can i turn that regex in a valide one?

**Thanks**

Comment: MySQL's `REGEXP` does not support lookaheads.  Can you edit your question and show more positive and negative matches?  There is probably a workaround.

Comment: is `;` always be at start and end of a field value?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, but if the "eventual regex-query solution" required a different structure i can change the sentence 's structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen updated!

thanks both of you

Comment: Cant you just use `like`? `SELECT * FROM table pl WHERE pl.description like '%;%batt%' and pl.description like'%;%lk%' and pl.description like '%;%elem%'`

Comment: MariaDB 10.0.5 has a richer set of REGEXP operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expensive.  You should seriously endeavor to improve/standardize your data storage for simpler/faster querying.

```
pl.`description` REGEXP 'batt[^;]*lk[^;]*elem|[^;]*lk[^;]*elem[^;]*batt'
```

This assumes (based on your sample input) that `elem` always follows `lk`, and `batt` can come before or after the other two substrings.

Comment: thanks 
in the end the only one way was yours: make n! combinations of n word to test every possibile positions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick that uses a variable.

There are 3 words, so that means there are only 6 combinations possible.
So the variable start with a pattern for 6 combinations.
And a replace changes it to a pattern that does it for the 3 words.

For example:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (id int, description varchar(100), rlikeit bool);

insert into test (id, description, rlikeit) values
(1,';lk elem batt;',true),
(2,';lk batt elem;',true),
(3,';elem lk batt;',true),
(4,';elem batt lk;',true),
(5,';batt lk elem;',true),
(6,';batt elem lk;',true),
(7,'; batt; lk; elem;',false),
(8,';batt batt batt;',false),
(9,'; lk Buttle, batt; Probatton with LK elements;',true),
(10,';look Buttle; Proton with LK elements;',false),
(11,';Brad Pitt the actor; LK elements in Battle;',true),
(12,';Brad Pitt the actor; LK elements in; Battle;',false);


set @pattern = ';x1x(2x3|3x2)|;x2x(1x3|3x1)|;x3x(1x2|2x1)';
-- set @pattern = '1x(2x3|3x2)|2x(1x3|3x1)|3x(1x2|2x1)'; -- shorter pattern
set @pattern = replace(replace(replace(replace(@pattern,
                 'x','[^;]*'),
                 '1','lk'),
                 '2','elem'),
                 '3','batt');

select * 
from test
where description RLIKE @pattern;
```

The select will only return the id's 1 to 6, 9 & 11.

Note that in a more complete regex engine, then it would be done with a pattern like f.e. `/;(?=[^;]*batt)(?=[^;]*lk)(?=[^;]*elem)[^;]*/i`.
But the MySQL REGEXP syntax sadly doesn't allow lookaheads.